# Do CUDA 3D memory copy parameters need to be kept alive?

Tags: cuda, cuda-context, cuda-driver

Consider the CUDA API function

```c++
CUresult cuMemcpy3DAsync (const CUDA_MEMCPY3D* pCopy, CUstream hStream);
```

described [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__MEM.html#group__CUDA__MEM_1g79f4f3fde6ae0f529568d881d9e11987).

It takes a `CUDA_MEMCPY3D` structure by pointer ; and this pointer is not to some CUDA-driver-created entity - it's to a structure the user has created.

My question: Do we need to keep the pointed-to structure alive past the call to this function returning? e.g. until after we've sycnrhonized the stream we've enqueued the copy on? Or - can we just discard it immediately? I'm guessing it should be the former, but the documentation doesn't really say.

Comment: cuMemcpy3DAsync  isn't a graph API function. It has been part of the vanilla driver API since CUDA was originally released

Comment: @talonmies: You're right, I initially asked this question about the `cuGraphAddMemcpyNode()` function, then noticed it was the same for just `cuMemcpy3DAsync()` itself, and forgot to edit that word out in the rewrite.

Comment: @paleonix: Removed it.